# Best open-source lossless CD ripper for Windows?

Tags: open-source, audio, optical-media, ripping

Any recommendations on good and widely used open-source lossless audio CD ripper for Windows?
I have plenty of original CDs that I want to throw away, but at least get the original quality song out of it first. Spotify is just not enough for my Hi-fi system :D

Comment: Free, but not open source: http://www.exactaudiocopy.de/en/

Comment: Can you explain ***why*** you ***need*** open source (not just free)? You are closing the door to a lot of potential answers. Btw, about 10 years ago, I used an app which interfaced to [MusicBrainz](https://musicbrainz.org/); the point being that your ripped music could have meaningful file names, plus MP3 tags. If you don't just want 00001.mp3,  00002.mp3, etc, then please update your question. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Windows' own built-in Media Player can rip CDs to WAV or AIFF - which is "original quality" 16-bit 44.1kHZ uncompressed, as well as to MP3 etc.
It's not open-source, but it's free ;)

After that you can convert to any format you like. For quality vs size, I'd recommend AAC over MP3, AAC can be lossy or lossless, just like FLAC, but has wider adoption for 'direct' playback from many devices.

Here's a list of all the formats [Windows Media Player supports](https://support.microsoft.com/help/316992/file-types-supported-by-windows-media-player)

Answer (score 1):

"Best" is relative but I'm a big fan of [cuetools/cueripper](http://cue.tools/wiki/Main_Page)

It handles Flac and quite a few other codecs with different back ends, does accurate rips and checks the rips against a DB. Its portableish (needs .net but no install) - so testing to see if it meets your needs would be pretty painless.